Deploying Blazor app to Azure Linux App Service - seemingly random web socket failures
[Update] I found a github issue that appears to be describing the same behavior: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/55442
I have a Blazor app that I have deployed to an Azure App Service.  The Blazor app is all InteractiveServer render mode.  After performing the same task several times succesfully I will suddenly get multiple console errors as shown below.  Every time it happens I can get back to normal with refreshing the page 1+ times (sometimes as many as 5 refreshes)

Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.


GET https://app-[removed]-001.azurewebsites.net/blazor?id=f9NSvVeKErKRUaRJWvmrfA&=1724694010721


Error: Failed to start the transport 'LongPolling': Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'


Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports. Error: WebSockets failed: Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled. ServerSentEvents failed: Error: 'ServerSentEvents' does not support Binary. Error: LongPolling failed: Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'

This is a small application that registers a DbContext, a ServiceBus Client, and a couple services; this is the full Program.cs
using HelpDesk.Components;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using HelpDesk.Services;
using HelpDesk.Data;
using MudBlazor.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddMudServices();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SpContext>(
    opt => opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StoredProcedureUser")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(ab => {
    ab.AddServiceBusClient(builder.Configuration["AzureWebJobsServiceBus"]);
});
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProceduresService, ProceduresService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ServiceBusService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

This is the .csproj:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>foo</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(RunConfiguration)' == 'https' " />
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(RunConfiguration)' == 'http' " />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.18.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.7.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="7.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


This is just a test project for me to try out Blazor.  The information I've found on why this might be happening:

App Service Plan; I'm on Basic so I shouldn't have an issue with the amount of WebSockets connections
Not using SignalR; I can't seem to find reliable information on if I must use SignalR or not.

I'm hoping someone has more insight into why this might be happening.

If possible, share your GitHub repo?

I can not share the repo, I'll try to extract more code to post

I'm not following why this would be closed.

Having the same issue with similar setup.

@Martin check your App Service configuration for the "Session affinity" setting and turn it on.  That appears to have resolved my issue but I'm going to let it run for a few days to confirm.
